# AngularJS select not populating dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following JSON (test JSON as how it comes from the server):

```
$scope.allCategoriesAndSubcategories = {
          "category" : {
              "categoryname" : "pasteleria",
              "subcategory" : [
                  {"subcategoryname" : "pastel tradicional", "subcategoryid" : "1"},
                  {"subcategoryname" : "pastel con fondant", "subcategoryid" : "2"}
              ]
          },
          "category" : {
              "categoryname" : "eventos",
              "subcategory" : [
                  {"subcategoryname" : "boda", "subcategoryid" : "1"},
                  {"subcategoryname" : "cumpleanos", "subcategoryid" : "2"}
              ]
          }
      };
```

Then on the select in the HTML I do the following:

```
<div input-field>
     <select material-select
     ng-model="picture.category1" required>
        <optgroup ng-repeat="category in allCategoriesAndSubcategories"  label="{{category.categoryname}}">
            <option value="{{category.subcategory.subcategoryid}}">{{category.subcategory.subcategoryname}}</option>
        </optgroup>
     </select>
     <label>Categoría #2</label>
</div>
```

When I `console.log()` I get the actual object so it's not undefined, however the select is not populating. Should I do something else to populate it? I'm new to angularJS and I can't find an example similar to this one

Comment: You mean it's not selecting the default value?

Comment: I mean it's not populating it. The select turns out to be undefined despite it having the value of a JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is invalid if you wish to create list of options

```
<div input-field>
     <select material-select ng-model="picture.category1" required>
        <optgroup ng-repeat="category in allCategoriesAndSubcategories"  label="{{category.categoryname}}">
            <option ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategory" value="{{subcategory.subcategoryid}}">{{subcategory.subcategoryname}}</option>
        </optgroup>
     </select>
     <label>Categoría #2</label>
</div>
```

then after you select element the model picture.category1 should be populated

working plunker http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/PZpRRy

also your data should be formatted differently

```
$scope.allCategoriesAndSubcategories = [{
      "categoryname": "pasteleria",
      "subcategory": [{
        "subcategoryname": "pastel tradicional",
        "subcategoryid": "1"
      }, {
        "subcategoryname": "pastel con fondant",
        "subcategoryid": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "categoryname": "eventos",
      "subcategory": [{
        "subcategoryname": "boda",
        "subcategoryid": "1"
      }, {
        "subcategoryname": "cumpleanos",
        "subcategoryid": "2"
      }]
    }];
  });
```

Comment: This works, however, for some reason, the first category is being ignored. As you can see, it only prints the second JSON set, not the first one.

Comment: @codeninja because you have a duplicated `key` on the ng-repeat.

Comment: Well that's because `allCategoriesAndSubcategories` is an object with duplicated key, it should be more like this http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/PZpRRy?editors=101

Comment: I understand now, however, why does the ng-repeat still have the category name in `category in allCategoriesAndSubcategories` since there's no object inside the JSON that is called category? This has always confused me

Comment: in that case `category` takes the value of whole object from array of objects. it can be whatever you want to use internally in ng-repeat. In other words: `ng-repeat="element in elements"` is a single element from array or object called `elements` hope that makes sense

Comment: Oh okay! Like a local variable inside the ng-repeat. Gotcha! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think that proble is here

```
 <option value="{{category.subcategory.subcategoryid}}">
```

Subcategory is array, and i think that you should use new `ng-repeat` to make list of `<option>` tags